# Constantly amending dataframe

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, lapply

I have a dataframe that generates from a folder that users will place several .csv files into. The .csv files will always have the same column structure, however they vary in row length. The idea is to make a single dataframe with all of the .csv files. When I use the code below with multiple .csv files I receive the following error message: "Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 88, 259"

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", path = dir, full.names = TRUE)
importDM<-lapply(temp, read.csv, header = TRUE)
rawDM <- as.data.frame(importDM) 

rawDM$Created.Date <- as.Date(rawDM$Created.Date...Time, format="%d/%m/%Y")

rawDM$Week <- strftime(rawDM$Created.Date,format="%W")
```

Something that will be an issue down the road as well is I want only the first .csv file added to be used for the header, as I believe with the code as it is will just lapply the header into the dataframe with each .csv file added.

Cheers,

Comment: Since `importDM` is a list of data frames, you probably want `rawDM = do.call(rbind, importDM)` rather than `as.data.frame`. If you want the header the first one to  be used, then before the `do.call` go through and set the names of each data frame to the names of the first one. `for (i in 2:length(importDM))  importDM[[i]] = setNames(importDM[[i]], names(importDM[[1]]))`.

Comment: Thanks Gregor for the speedy response! However it did not work for me!

"Error in as.Date.default(rawDM$Created.Date...Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'rawDM$Created.Date...Time' to class “Date”"
Forgot to mention I have a date conversion code I have edited original post.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer on a blog elsewhere, here was the final code:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", path = dir, full.names = TRUE)
importDM<-do.call("rbind", lapply(temp, read.csv, header = TRUE))
rawDM <- as.data.frame(importDM)
```